# saving serialized sortable in form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

i have a simple form, it has 3 text inputs, a sortable li list and a hidden input to which the sortable output will go to.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        stop: function (event, ui) {
    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            document.getElementsByName("order").value = data;
 }
    });
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form>
    
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li id="item-1">Item 1</li>
        <li id="item-2">Item 2</li>
        <li id="item-3">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name">
        <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="last name">
        <br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone">
        <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="order" value="">
        
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        
</form>
```

i wish to do 2 things:

1) getting the string output from the serialized sortable into the value of the hidden "order" input.

2a) making the output easier to work with (something like "1,2,3" instead of "item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=3")

2b) saving the data of the form to mysql in the following form using php.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can suscribe to the submit event of the form and and use a function to first save the serialized sortable into the hidden input.

2a) I think that is better to work with that and then use php to transform the array in other format you prefer.

2b) Searching in Google you will find info about how to do that.